# Basic Linear Algebra problem about representing a vector space as its proper subspaces union

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ is a vector space over an infinte field $F$.
Assume that $n<\infty$ and $W_i$ $(1<i<n \land i ,n\in\Bbb N)$ are proper subspaces of $V$.$(W_i\neq V \land W_i\neq \emptyset)$

Prove that we can't represent $V$ this way:

$V=\cup_1^n W_i=W_1\cup W_2\cup...\cup W_n$

I am spending my first course in linear algebra so i am not familiar with common concepts such as dimension or basis or...
I am just starting this course and I only understand concepts like vector spaces or subspaces or fields or...
please help me to solve this problem

thank you...

Comment: But one actually *can* represent a vector space as a finite union of its subspaces when it’s finite, and it could be. So—at least in full generality—your claim is invalid.

Comment: @arseniiv
You are right...
But I didn't write my question properly so I edit it...
please check it again...
thank you for your consideration...

Comment: OK. But now this question has been marked as a duplicate of another; could you please elaborate what’s in answers to that one is still unclear?

Comment: Sure.
In answers you can see concepts are used that I am not familiar with which are not necessary to solve the problem according to my textbook.

Comment: I had just reread answers there, and I think there isn’t a point trying to pick out dimension arguments, as even the resulting proof –not to mean translation process– would be tedious and uninspiring. An unlucky situation.